# Ng-Click - Try to pass data in my Firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, angularjs-ng-click

I have range and I want pass his data in my firebase.

I've try ng-submit but it's don't work ...

This is my Range :

```
     <div class="item range range-balanced">
    5km
    <input type="range" name="distance" min="5" max="50" value="20" ng-model="distance">
    50km
  </div>
      <button class="button button-block button-balanced" id="confirm-distance" ng-click="addDistance({{distance}})">
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Confirmer {{distance}} Km
    </button>
```

And my JS :

```
$scope.addDistance = function(dist) {

      userRef.child($scope.currentUser.authResponse.userID).child("settings").set({
        distance: distance
      })

    }
```

How can I do for pass data in my firebase ? (All my firebase reference are defined)

Thank's all for answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ng-click` should not have `{{}}` interpolation directive in it, you could directly mention scope variable in it.

```
<button class="button button-block button-balanced" 
   id="confirm-distance" 
   ng-click="addDistance(distance)">
     <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Confirmer {{distance}} Km
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you bro you save my day ;)

Comment: @YngDev31 Glad to help you..Thanks :)